# Detect the last usage of a custom command in a custom environment

Tags: macros, environments

I have a custom macro and custom environment.

```
\begin{myenv}
...
\mycmd
...
\mycmd
...
\mycmd % last usage
...
\end{myenv}
```

I want to detect the first & last usage of `\mycmd` and print something special with them. Currently I am using `\toggletrue`, `\togglefalse`, and `\iftoggle` to detect first usage. However, I cannot figure out how to detect the last usage. How do I do this?

P.S. I cannot modify the usage of the command, as I am making this as part of a `.cls` for auto-generated documents.

Comment: You need two passes. Either read the content of `myenv` into a macro and process that twice or write something to the aux file.

Comment: The last `\mycmd` is considered the last in a specific environment or the last in the document? Is there only one of such environments which can contain `\mycmd`?

Comment: is `\mycmd` always at "top" level in your environment, i.e. neither inside braces ? (being in sub-environment is still ok)

Comment: @jfbu why would braces matter?

Comment: Is `\mycmd` only ever used inside the `myenv` environment? Or could it occur anywhere between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`?

Comment: @Skillmon I wanted to use delimited macros, so a `\mycmd` in braces could not see the end of the environment; also it would not be seen by an earlier `\mycmd`. (edited comment as original had myenv and not \mycmd by oversight; this comment refers to initial version of my answer)

Comment: For my purposes, `\mycmd` might occur in 2-level nested environments, though I can probably engineer around it in the current input set. `\mycmd` is only used inside `myenv`. 

Thank you all for the answers and responses. This is part of a project to generate PDF reports from JSON. The JSON varies in structure but has some consistency. I will try to evaluate which one I can make work with existing code I have right now.

Answer (score 5):

### Edit for more robust approach

The initial answer has the defect to tie `\mycmd` to usage only inside environment `myenv` and also it will create low-level TeX error if `\mycmd` is used inside braces.

Following [this suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391637/detect-the-last-usage-of-a-custom-command-in-a-custom-environment/391640?noredirect=1#comment972848_391640) of @BrunoLeFloch I modify the logic: in new method, command `\mycmd` is not tied at all to environment `myenv` but it is environment `myenv` whose definition is modified to (using `\Collect@Body` from package [environ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ)) gather its body (hence, as in earlier method, this is not compatible with usage of verbatim material in it), and to parse it in order to replace the last found `\mycmd` token by `\mycmdLAST` token. Hence one only needs to define `\mycmdLAST` to do whatever is desired.

In this approach `\mycmd` is not re-defined, it can also be used inside braces in the environment without errors, but it can not then be detected. In the example I define `\mycmdLAST` (as per Bruno's comment) to locally re-define `\mycmd` so if it is encountered after `\mycmdLAST` (necessarily hidden in braces) it will raise deliberately some error message. But this is up to document author to decide what the macro should do in those cases.

**To recapitulate**: the user needs only to load package `environ` and to put last in the "begin" part of the environment definition the two tokens `\Collect@Body\mycmd@Parse`. The environment name is arbitrary but the command name must be `\mycmd`. The command `\mycmd` can be used everywhere in the document and needs no special definition. It is mandatory though to define a `\mycmdLAST` command (a priori with the same number of arguments as original `\mycmd` but it could set a toggle and then insert the token `\mycmd`, the latter fetching the arguments and having been defined to check the toggle), and if `\mycmd` was the last one in the environment, then `\mycmdLAST` is executed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter

\newtoks\mytoksA
\newtoks\mytoksB

\newenvironment{myenv}{BEGIN CODE OF ENVIRONMENT\par
                       \Collect@Body\mycmd@Parse}
                      {\par END CODE OF ENVIRONMENT\par}

\long\def\mycmd@Parse #1{\mytoksA{}%
                         \mycmd@Parse@start\empty#1\mycmd\mycmd@Parse@start
                         \the\mytoksA}

\long\def\mycmd@Parse@start #1\mycmd{%
    \mytoksB\expandafter{#1}%
    \futurelet\mycmd@Token
    \mycmd@Parse@checkifnone
}%

\def\mycmd@Parse@checkifnone {%
    \ifx\mycmd@Token\mycmd@Parse@start
        \mytoksA\expandafter{\the\mytoksB}% no use of \mycmd in environment
        \expandafter\@gobbletwo % get rid of \mycmd@Parse@start end token
    \else
        \expandafter\mycmd@Parse@loop
    \fi\empty
}%

\long\def\mycmd@Parse@loop #1\mycmd{%
    \mytoksA\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
           {\expandafter\the\expandafter\mytoksA\the\mytoksB}%
    \mytoksB\expandafter{#1}%
    \futurelet\mycmd@Token
    \mycmd@Parse@check % check if we had hit earlier the last \mycmd
}%

\def\mycmd@Parse@check {%
    \ifx\mycmd@Token\mycmd@Parse@start
        \mytoksA\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          {\expandafter\the\expandafter\mytoksA\expandafter
           \mycmdLAST
           \the\mytoksB}%
        \expandafter\@gobbletwo % get rid of \mycmd@Parse@start end token
    \else
        \mytoksA\expandafter{\the\mytoksA\mycmd}%
        \expandafter\mycmd@Parse@loop
    \fi\empty
}%

\makeatother

\newcommand\mycmdLAST{% whatever is wanted
    % use same number of arguments as \mycmd
    \textcolor{blue}{\bfseries I am last!}%
    % optional: (use same number of arguments as \mycmd)
    \renewcommand{\mycmd}% just an example
        {{\color{red}ERROR: USAGE INSIDE BRACES AFTER LAST ONE AT TOP LEVEL}}%
}

\newcommand\mycmd{\textcolor{red}{\bfseries I WAS HERE!}}

\begin{document}

Test 1:

\begin{myenv}\mycmd
  \begin{description}
\item[xintbinhex] \mycmd 
  is for conversions to and from binary and
  hexadecimal \mycmd bases.

\item[xintseries] provides some \emph{\mycmd basic functionality} for computing in an
  expandable manner partial sums of series and power series with fractional
  coefficients.\mycmd

\item[xintgcd] implements {\footnotesize\mycmd} the Euclidean algorithm and its typesetting.\mycmd

\item[xintcfrac] \mycmd deals with the computation of continued fractions.
\end{description}
\end{myenv}

\bigskip

Test 2:

\begin{myenv}
  No usage of \texttt{\string\mycmd} here.
\end{myenv}

\bigskip

Test 3:

\begin{myenv}
  \mycmd
  Here we have a braced one after the last usage {\mycmd}
\end{myenv}

\bigskip

Test 4:

\begin{myenv}
  Here we have only a braced one {\mycmd}
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Earlier answer

Here is a method requiring only one pass and without multiple expansions of contents.

Defect: you can not nest your custom `myenv` (else the test for being last will have false positives for the `\mycmd` in the outer one).

Defect 2: a `\mycmd` inside braces will not be detected by the other ones, hence possibly cause a false positive. Besides a `\mycmd` inside braces will probably lead to a TeX error because it will not find the `\end{myenv}` it is looking for.

In brief, this solution is fine for `\mycmd` at top level inside a single `myenv` environment, and they may actually be inside sub-environments (but not again `myenv`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{myenv}{}{}
\newcommand{\myenvname}{myenv}

\newif\ifmycmdlast
\newtoks\mytoksA
\newtoks\mytoksB

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\mycmd}{\mytoksA{}\mycmd@\empty}%
% \empty token serves to avoid brace removal next

\long\def\mycmd@#1\end#2{%
    \mytoksB\expandafter{#1\end{#2}}%
    \mytoksA\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          {\expandafter\the\expandafter\mytoksA\the\mytoksB}%
    \long\def\mycmd@temp{#2}%
    \ifx\mycmd@temp\myenvname
        \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
        \expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
    \mycmd@check{\mycmd@\empty}%
}%

\def\mycmd@check
   {\expandafter\mycmd@check@i\the\mytoksA\mycmd\mycmd\mycmd@temp}

\long\def\mycmd@check@i #1\mycmd#2\mycmd#3\mycmd@temp{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
        \mycmdlasttrue
    \else
        \mycmdlastfalse
    \fi
    \expandafter\myRealCmd\the\mytoksA
}
\makeatother

\newcommand\myRealCmd{% whatever is wanted
    \ifmycmdlast
       \textbf{\textcolor{blue}{I am last}}%
    \else
       \textbf{\textcolor{red}{I am not last}}%
    \fi
}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}
  \begin{description}
\item[xintbinhex] \mycmd 
  is for conversions to and from binary and
  hexadecimal \mycmd bases.

\item[xintseries] provides some basic functionality for computing in an
  expandable manner partial sums of series and power series with fractional
  coefficients.\mycmd

\item[xintgcd] implements the Euclidean algorithm and its typesetting.\mycmd

\item[xintcfrac] deals with the computation of continued fractions.
\end{description}
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I actually wanted this test:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{myenv}\mycmd
  \begin{description}
\item[xintbinhex] \mycmd 
  is for conversions to and from binary and
  hexadecimal \mycmd bases.

\item[xintseries] provides some basic functionality for computing in an
  expandable manner partial sums of series and power series with fractional
  coefficients.\mycmd

\item[xintgcd] implements the Euclidean algorithm and its typesetting.\mycmd

\item[xintcfrac] deals with the computation of continued fractions.
\end{description}
\mycmd
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: I also forgot to say that the method is not compatible with usage of `verbatim` or other catcode changing environments or macros (except those using `\scantokens`) because it fetches tokens and hence TeX assigns catcodes at that time which can't be changed (if not using `\scantokens`) afterwards.

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to use `environ` to define `myenv` to look for `\mycmd` and replace the last one by `\mylastcmd`, defined as `\newcommand{\mylastcmd}{...\renewcommand{\mycmd}{\ERROR}}` so that any use of `\mycmd` in braces after `\mylastcmd` would produce an error?

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I was just going for the simple minded approach with no auxiliary file nor e-TeX stuff nor extra package ;-) I would say your idea isn't simpler but is certainly better, as it is more general (allowing braced `\mycmd`). It is another answer, you should post it!

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch actually you did write `safer` and not `simpler`! I have to adjust my eyeglasses! Anyway, fully agreed. Do post your better answer!

Comment: I don't have time, so the lazy approach was to suggest the idea to you :)

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch done... I will communicate Paypal account details offline for re-imbursement of my work hours!

Comment: I suspect as the document is generated by some software that handing over to that software the detection of case of last usage in environment could be an easier method.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a simple approach, that does work, but if `myenv` does contain stuff like figures or anything numbered, this leads to problems, as the full content is evaluated twice (once inside a box, which isn't printed), note that `\mycmd@orig` should contain the correct macro-definition, as `\mycmd` gets defined inside the environment.

**EDIT:** I've added the possibility to specify counters which should be reset after the box-test. By default the contents of `\countlist` is reset, but one can give additional counters as an optional argument to `myenv`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\makeatletter
\def\csedef#1#2{\expandafter\edef\csname#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcount\mycmdcount
\def\countlist{figure,table}
\def\b@ckupcount@myenv{%
  \@for\cs:=\countlist\do{%
    \csedef{b@ckup@myenv@\cs}{\the\value{\cs}}}}
\def\rest@recount@myenv{%
  \@for\cs:=\countlist\do{%
    \setcounter{\cs}{\csname b@ckup@myenv@\cs\endcsname}}}
\newenvironment*{myenv}[1][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
  \else%
    \edef\countlist{\countlist,#1}%
  \fi%
  \grab@myenv%
}{%
}
\def\mycmd@orig{%
  \global\advance\mycmdcount by 1\relax%
  \ifnum\mycmdcount=1\relax%
    first usage%
  \else%
    \expandafter\ifnum\lastmycmdcount=\mycmdcount\relax%
      last usage%
    \else%
      a usage, not the first, not the last%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\def\grab@myenv#1\END{%
  \mycmdcount=0\relax%
  \b@ckupcount@myenv%
  \bgroup%
  \def\mycmd{\global\advance\mycmdcount by 1\relax}%
  \setbox0\vbox{#1}%
  \xdef\lastmycmdcount{\the\mycmdcount}%
  \egroup%
  \rest@recount@myenv%
  \let\mycmd\mycmd@orig%
  \mycmdcount=0\relax%
  #1%
  \end}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\begin{myenv}[section]
  \section{foo}
  foo bar baz\\
  \mycmd\\% first
  foo bar baz\\
  \mycmd\\% another usage
  foo bar baz\\
  \mycmd\\% last
\END{myenv}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This assumes `\mycmd` always appears explicitly (not called by other macros). The idea is to search for `\mycmd` that's not followed by any other call of itself up to the end; the regex is

```
\c{mycmd}([^\c{mycmd]*)\Z
```

which exactly fits the description.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{myenv}
 {
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
   { \c{mycmd}([^\c{mycmd}]*)\Z }
   { \c{mycmdLAST}\1 }
   \BODY
  \BODY
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\mycmdLAST{% whatever is wanted
  \textcolor{blue}{\bfseries I am last!}%
}

\newcommand\mycmd{\textcolor{red}{\bfseries I WAS HERE!}}

\begin{document}

Test 1:

\begin{myenv}\mycmd
  \begin{description}
\item[xintbinhex] \mycmd 
  is for conversions to and from binary and
  hexadecimal \mycmd bases.

\item[xintseries] provides some \emph{\mycmd{} basic functionality} for computing in an
  expandable manner partial sums of series and power series with fractional
  coefficients.\mycmd

\item[xintgcd] implements {\footnotesize\mycmd} the Euclidean algorithm and its typesetting.\mycmd

\item[xintcfrac] \mycmd deals with the computation of continued fractions.
\end{description}
\end{myenv}

\bigskip

Test 2:

\begin{myenv}
  No usage of \texttt{\string\mycmd} here.
\end{myenv}

\bigskip

Test 3:

\begin{myenv}
  \mycmd{}
  Here we have a braced one after the last usage {\mycmd} with something after
\end{myenv}

\bigskip

Test 4:

\begin{myenv}
  Here we have only a braced one {\mycmd}
\end{myenv}

Test 5:

\begin{myenv}
  Here we have only a braced one {\mycmd} and something after
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

I used essentially the same tests as in jfbu's answer.

[image]

You can extend it to also catch the first usage; of course you have to decide what happens in case there's a single occurrence of `\mycmd`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{myenv}
 {
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
   { \c{mycmd} }
   { \c{mycmdFIRST} }
   \BODY
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
   { \c{mycmd}([^\c{mycmd}]*)\Z }
   { \c{mycmdLAST}\1 }
   \BODY
  \BODY
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\mycmd{\textcolor{red}{\bfseries I WAS HERE!}}
\newcommand\mycmdFIRST{\textcolor{green}{\bfseries I am first!}}
\newcommand\mycmdLAST{% whatever is wanted
  \textcolor{blue}{\bfseries I am last!}%
}

\begin{document}

Test 1:

\begin{myenv}\mycmd
  \begin{description}
\item[xintbinhex] \mycmd 
  is for conversions to and from binary and
  hexadecimal \mycmd bases.

\item[xintseries] provides some \emph{\mycmd{} basic functionality} for computing in an
  expandable manner partial sums of series and power series with fractional
  coefficients.\mycmd

\item[xintgcd] implements {\footnotesize\mycmd} the Euclidean algorithm and its typesetting.\mycmd

\item[xintcfrac] \mycmd deals with the computation of continued fractions.
\end{description}
\end{myenv}

\bigskip

Test 2:

\begin{myenv}
  No usage of \texttt{\string\mycmd} here.
\end{myenv}

\bigskip

Test 3:

\begin{myenv}
  \mycmd{}
  Here we have a braced one after the last usage {\mycmd} with something after
\end{myenv}

\bigskip

Test 4:

\begin{myenv}
  Here we have only a braced one {\mycmd}
\end{myenv}

Test 5:

\begin{myenv}
  Here we have only a braced one {\mycmd} and something after
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For instance, we can decide that a lonely appearance of `\mycmd` executes `\mycmdLONELY`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{myenv}
 {
  \regex_count:nVN { \c{mycmd} } \BODY \l_tmpa_int
  \int_compare:nTF { \l_tmpa_int < 2 }
   { % less than two occurrences
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { \c{mycmd} } { \c{mycmdLONELY} } \BODY
   }
   {
    \regex_replace_once:nnN
     { (.*?)\c{mycmd}(.*)\c{mycmd}([^\c{mycmd}]*) }
     { \1 \c{mycmdFIRST} \2 \c{mycmdLAST} \3 }
     \BODY
   }
  % deliver the contents
  \BODY
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_count:nnN { nV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\mycmd{\textcolor{red}{\bfseries I WAS HERE!}}
\newcommand\mycmdLONELY{\textcolor{green!50!blue}{\bfseries I feel lonely!}}
\newcommand\mycmdFIRST{\textcolor{green}{\bfseries I am first!}}
\newcommand\mycmdLAST{\textcolor{blue}{\bfseries I am last!}}

\begin{document}

Test 1:

\begin{myenv}\mycmd
  \begin{description}
\item[xintbinhex] \mycmd 
  is for conversions to and from binary and
  hexadecimal \mycmd bases.

\item[xintseries] provides some \emph{\mycmd{} basic functionality} for computing in an
  expandable manner partial sums of series and power series with fractional
  coefficients.\mycmd

\item[xintgcd] implements {\footnotesize\mycmd} the Euclidean algorithm and its typesetting.\mycmd

\item[xintcfrac] \mycmd deals with the computation of continued fractions.
\end{description}
\end{myenv}

\bigskip

Test 2:

\begin{myenv}
  No usage of \texttt{\char`\\mycmd} here.
\end{myenv}

\bigskip

Test 3:

\begin{myenv}
  \mycmd{}
  Here we have a braced one after the last usage {\mycmd} with something after
\end{myenv}

\bigskip

Test 4:

\begin{myenv}
  Here we have only a braced one {\mycmd}
\end{myenv}

Test 5:

\begin{myenv}
  Here we have only a braced one {\mycmd} and something after
\end{myenv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: peripherical to main: I am not familiar with `\NewEnviron` but assuming `myenv` is supposed to do other things how do you insert that in it? isn't here simpler with just adding some `\Collect@Body` usage to original OP's `myenv` environment definition?

Comment: @jfbu `\NewEnviron` is just an easier interface to `\Collect@Body`.

Comment: but does it allow the "end" part? the doc which I skimmed mentions an optional argument for "final tokens", it was not clear on reading if this serves as equivalent to the "end" part of standard environment. (I understand the user can add the end tokens directly after `\BODY` usage, but possibly not quite same as end tokens from end part of standard environment)

Comment: @jfbu `\NewEnviron` takes a trailing optional argument; it's explained in the doc.

Comment: ah ok. Indeed it is exactly equivalent to the end part from standard environment. On first reading I wasn't sure.